# Building and Linking Crypto++ CMake

Tags: c++, intellij-idea, cmake, clion, crypto++

I am trying to build and link the simplest program in CLion on Linux Mint that uses the Crypto++ Library. I've searched high and low for information on how to tell CMake where my libraries are but I'm having trouble finding relevant information.

What do I need to add to CMake to get this to successfully build, link and run?

Screenshots and Pastebin follows:
    [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjobf.png)
    [CMake File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXf96.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake link to external library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library)

Comment: For future questions: code and error messages should be **in the question post as text**, not linked as images.

Comment: Downvoted because of everything not posted in the question.  Once resolved add a comment with "@UKMonkey" and I'll remove my downvote

Comment: Also see [CMake](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CMake) on the Crypto++ wiki. There is a section [Importing Crypto++](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CMake#Importing_Crypto.2B.2B) that is intended to cover the use case, but I am not sure how correct it is.

Comment: Another item of interest is [Crypto++ Issue 249, How to find crypto++ package using cmake?](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/249) Unfortunately we never got a satisfying feeling from Issue 249. The CMake manual lacks instructions on the CMake find file, and their mailing list was closed to new subscriptions so we could not ask questions.

Comment: @jww Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/47841679/2799037 What do you mean by closed? Last time I tried I was able to subsscribe and post.

Comment: @usr1234567 - *"What do you mean by closed?"* - the self-serve account creation or signup was disabled. I think it was due to bots and spam.